# Exception handling while inserting the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I am inserting data using a stored proc and i want to handle exceptions how can i do it?What kind of exceptions i can get and how can i throw them?

```
 public int insert(string fname,string lname,string city)
  {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cstr);
      try
      {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert", con);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox1.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBox2.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox3.Text);
          con.Open();
         return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          throw;
      }
   finally
      {
          con.Close();
      }
  }
```

Comment: are you looking for test cases?

Comment: What you want to do with the exceptions? if you simply rethrow then why catching them?

Comment: What can i do after catching them??

Answer (score 1):

Best is to catch specific Exception, not the base `Exception`. You may catch [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) and then throw the same, if it is being handled later. Also use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with your connection which will work as try/finally block.

Comment: How can i catch a specific exception?how can i throw it?

Comment: `catch (SqlException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }`

Comment: If you've caught it, why do you want to throw it?

Comment: What kind of exceptions i may get here??

Comment: I already said - `SqlException`. What is it that you aren't understanding?

Comment: As i am not using a console application how can i catch it in normal aspx page?

Comment: @tomfanning catch (SqlException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

when i do like this i am getting an error like return value is missing,what can i return here?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)` is probably just to show you the code block, what you actually need is just a throw statement. So your code should be `catch(SqlException) { throw; }`

Comment: @Chandrasekhar Depends on why you've caught the exception. Think about what you're doing. If you have chosen to catch the exception, what do you want to happen? If you want to return a value, do so (`return -1;` perhaps). If you don't know what to return, you probably shouldn't have caught the exception. Just put some effort into thinking about why you're writing every bit of code you write. There should be a reason every line of code you write is how it is - and you should be thinking about that reason ALL of the time.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlException` should be handling in upper layer if you want to do some business logic with it. If you don't just let it throw naturally and log exception if needed.

In here just use `using` keyword as best practice.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(cstr))
  {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBox2.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox3.Text);
      con.Open();

     return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want info of what Exceptions the ExecuteNonQuery function throws you only have to look into MSDN page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Just do as Habib says, instead of

```
catch(Exception)
```

You should catch the specific exception types as appropriate for your situation:

```
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
```

and in the catch, do whatever you have to do when SqlException is thrown.

Comment: Argh, no, don't do this! There's a very clear list of what exception types can be thrown - catch them if you can actually handle them (i.e. if you might reasonably expect them at runtime for some reason), otherwise don't catch them at all!

Comment: @tomfanning of course is better not to do that, I edit the answer properly to warn about this. you're right

Comment: I removed the code - hope you don't mind - and upvoted the rest of your answer because it's actually useful.

Comment: @tomfanning ok, no problem, just decided to leave there just to warn, sometimes is better to say what's wrong to warn people about its use. But it's correct, this is one of that moments to keep quiet and give only the right answer :) Thanks for your help, and the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` throws `InvalidCastException`, `SqlException`, `IOException`, `InvalidOperationException`, and `ObjectDisposedException`.

By the way, what's with this?

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open method scope like ExecuteNonQuery(  you will see List of Exceptions it could throw in most situations so if you want to catch specific exceptions.

than you can use for ex. : catch(System.InvalidCastException exception) to catch this specific exception